# Maven infinispan quickstart

Tags: maven, infinispan, classnotfound

I compiled Infinispan quickstart and when I am trying to run I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Quickstart (wrong nam
e: org/infinispan/quickstart/embeddedcache/Quickstart)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Quickstart.  Program will exit.
```

I am following this tutorial.

https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/embedded-cache

Though I am not using any IDE so that I can learn how maven works with infinispan. From command prompt prompt I am using this command To compile,

```
mvn clean compile dependency:copy-dependencies -DstripVersion
```

and then, to run,

`java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Quickstart`

It is compiling successfully.
I have tried to compile and then run the quickstart from within target directory where the class file is kept. But I am getting the same error class found .....

Thanks
Meena

Anyhelp will be appreciated.

Comment: You should show us your pom.xml file.  It think you are missing a dependency.

Comment: If you're on Windows the cp should have ; as separator `java -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Quickstart`

Answer (score 4):

Try running with

`java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* org.infinispan.quickstart.embeddedcache.Quickstart`